# Error al subir fichero a Amazon S3 con Android

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual debo subir ficheros a Amazon S3, utilizando la librería **aws-java-sdk-1.11.501**. El código es el siguiente, tomado de AWS:

```
private void UploadObject() {
    String region = "nameregion";
    String bucketName = "nameBucket";
    String accessKey = "*************";
    String secretKey = "*******************************";
    String mNamePDF = "PDF-Uploads3.pdf";

    try {
        File filePath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + File.separator +  "1757133747" + File.separator + mNamePDF);

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();

        // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, accessKey, filePath);
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
        metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
        request.setMetadata(metadata);
        s3Client.putObject(request);

    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Cuando se debuggea el proyecto en la línea `.build()` Android Studio abre una clase llamada Looper.class y muestra el siguiente error:

```
Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/MBeanServerFactory;
```

Por favor alguna ayuda al respecto. Estaría muy agradecido
Saludos

Comment: Básicamente el problema está en que estas utilizando la librería propia para java y no la destinada para android, ya que android utiliza otro tipo de clases destinadas para la plataforma, consulta la [Documetación del SDK para Android](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-android/index.html#lang/es_es).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero cuando uso las librerías para Android en este caso `aws-android-sdk-s3.jar`  para conectarse a Amazon S3, el IDE no reconoce AmazonS3ClientBuilder para declarar el objeto propio de Amazon S3. De igual forma vuelvo a leer la documentación en busca de alguna respuesta al respecto.